# Comparing stored time string to DateTime('now')

Tags: php, datetime-conversion, datetime-comparison

I'm storing time as a string in my database... hopefully that's not my problem, I need to compare that stored time/date to the current time/date and get days/hours/minutes.

It's stored in this format... 11-10 07:42 PM

I assign that string to $storedTime.

`$storedTime = "11-10 07:42 PM";`

Get the current time like...

`$now = new DateTime('now');`

`$now->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));`

`$now = $now->format('m-d h:i A');`

Convert my variable to time like..

`$time = new DateTime(strtotime($storedTime));`

and format it...

`$time1 = $time->format('m-d h:i A');`

Try to compare the two times and I get an error that I'm still passing a string to diff()

`$interval = $time1->diff($now);`

`echo $interval->format('%s second(s)');`

I've tried sooo many different variations that my brain is fried lol help please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the `->format` method on the `DateTime` class you are converting your object to a string. I believe this is where your problem lays.

See my example below to how this was solved. You can apply directly to your problem as you see fit.

```
$storedTime = "11-10 07:42 PM";
$convertedTime = DateTime::createFromFormat("m-d h:i A", $storedTime);
$convertedTime->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));

$now = new DateTime('now');
$now->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Los_Angeles'));

$diff = $convertedTime->diff($now);
$diff_string = $diff->format('%s second(s)');

print($diff_string);
```

Comment: You nailed it. Thanks a lot, I appreciate it. I added `$elapsed = $diff->format('%a days %h hours %i minutes');` to get my final result of days and hours